# Darker Google userscript not working in Tampermonkey 4.7

Tags: userscripts, tampermonkey, userstyles

I'm trying to install the [Darker Google](https://userstyles.org/styles/43463/darker-google) userscript in Tampermonkey 4.7 (for Safari 12), but it's not working.

Since I'm a total newbie on Tampermonkey I don't really know where to put my hands on.

In the Tampermonkey's dashboard I see that this userscript does not match any particular website, while for example [Darker Facebook](https://userstyles.org/styles/100480/darker-facebook) shows "*.facebook.com" and it works, but perhaps this is just a bad guess.

The beginning of the userscript is:

```
(function() {var css = "";
css += [
        "/* Darker Google by Zigboom Designs */",
        "",
        "@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);"
    ].join("\n");
if (false ||
    (document.location.href.indexOf("http://blogsearch.google") == 0) ||
    (document.location.href.indexOf("http://books.google") == 0) ||
    (document.location.href.indexOf("http://209.85.165.104") == 0) ||
    (document.location.href.indexOf("http://translate.google") == 0) ||
    (document.location.href.indexOf("http://video.google") == 0) ||
    (document.location.href.indexOf("https://encrypted.google") == 0) ||
    (document.location.href.indexOf("https://translate.google") == 0) ||
    (document.location.href.indexOf("http://scholar.google") == 0) ||
    (document.location.href.indexOf("https://scholar.google") == 0) ||
    (document.location.href.indexOf("http://images.google") == 0) ||
    (document.location.href.indexOf("https://images.google") == 0) ||
    (document.location.href.indexOf("https://www.google.com/fonts") == 0) ||
    (new RegExp("^https?://www\\.google\\.[a-z.]*/(?!calendar|nexus|adsense|analytics|maps).*$")).test(document.location.href))
```

which makes me thing it *should* match any *.google.com website... but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the userscript is not running in the page. Add the following line, save it and reload the page.

`// @match         *://*.google.com/*`

The above makes the userscript to run on Google sites.

For match-patterns, [refer here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)